# Flyout search box with css

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to implement search box that appears on button click and hides on click somewhere outside. I'm trying to implement this with css.

I have next html:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="search">
  <div id="mobileSearch" class="search-by-name form-group ember-view">
    <div tabindex="0" role="button" id="ember415" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-power-select-typeahead-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view">
     <input type="search" id="ember-power-select-typeahead-input-ember410"  class="ember-power-select-typeahead-input ember-power-select-search-input">
    </div>
    <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember410" style="display: none;" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder"></div>    
  </div>
  <div type="button" class="btn mobile-search-button"></div>
</div>
```

And scss:

```
.navbar {          
  > .container-fluid {    
    > .navbar-header {      
      > .search {
        > #mobileSearch {
          width: 42px;
          height: 42px;
          display: inline;

          > div {
            margin-top: 15px;
            display: inline;
            height: 42px;
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            margin-left: 42px;
            padding: 0;
            border: none;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
          }
        }
      }

      > .search:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      .search > #mobileSearch > div:focus,
      > .search:focus > #mobileSearch > div {
        min-width: 220px;
        max-width: 220px;
        padding: 2px 16px 2px 8px;
        margin-left: -178px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }   

      .mobile-search-button {
        width: 42px;
        height: 42px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url('/assets/search-128.png');
        background-size: cover;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When user clicks on button search box appears, and when he clicks outside it hides. This part works OK. But when user move focus to input field search box also hides. I understand that issue was related to search box structure (div with div with div with input) but I can't change last layers (div with input) because it is plugin's component.

I would prefer a solution without Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
.search:focus-within
```

it will work with .search and all child elements